# Embed one html file inside other report html file as hyperlink in python

Tags: python, html, hyperlink

I am trying to embed a A.html file inside B.html(report) file as a hyperlink.

Just to be clear, both html files are offline and available only on my local machine. and at last the report html file will be sent over email.

The email recipient will not be having access to my local machine. So if they click on hyperlink in report.html, they will get "`404 - File or directory not found`".

Is there any way to embed `A.html` inside `report.html`, so that email recipient can open `A.html` from `report.html` on their machine

Comment: Should show us your html code

Answer (score 0):

You need to one of:

1. Attach A.html as well as report.html,
2. Post A.html to a shared location such as Google drive and modify the link to point to it, or
3. Put the content of A.html into a hidden `<div>` with a show method.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I know this will be a workaround. But is it not possible just to embed the whole A.html file inside report.html. 

Its because A.html and report.html are created when i run the script, so is it not possible to embed A.html inside report.html, there must be some way right?

Comment: That is what option 3 does. You could even do it by replacing the link with the content of A.html i.e. all the bits between `<body>` and `</body>` then it will display all of the time.